What were your biggest challenges renting a place in Japan as a student or business trip?
I’m really curious about the process of finding and renting a place to live in Japan. If you’ve ever gone through this, I’d love to hear your personal stories or any major hurdles you faced. Is there anything you want to be improved?

Welcome to Expatriates. As written, your question is far to broad and highly likely to get closed. What has your own research on the topic revealed? What is the actual problem you need help with?
